# Django Update/Delete view. Handling user permissions

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

models.py

```
class Punch(models.Model):
ro_number = models.IntegerField()
flag = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
actual = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def efficiency(self):
    return '%.2f' % (float(self.flag)/float(self.actual)*100)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.ro_number)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^flags/update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.PunchEdit.as_view(), name='update_flags'),
```

view.py

```
class PunchEdit(views.LoginRequiredMixin,
            UpdateView,):
model = Punch
fields = ['ro_number', 'flag', 'actual', 'description']
template_name = 'free/home.html'

def get_success_url(self):
    pass
```

I am trying to figure out how to allow users to only edit the punch objects they created. Any time a Punch object is created it saves which user created the punch with a foreign key relation. (Accomplished in views not shown)

Right now if you were to type in something like **mywebsite.com/punch/update/(pk)/** a user could write in the pk of any punch object and update its info.

So my question is.. How, when using class based generic update/delete views, can you prevent a user from touching a punch object they did not create themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the user in the [`.dispatch()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) method, or in a [`.process_request()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin) middleware, or create a Permissions class to extend in your views. I will write a brief example with the first option:

```
class PunchEdit(...):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # check for user logged in
        ...
        # check for user permission:
        # Take pk from kwargs
        pk = kwargs.get('pk')  # example
        # Take user from request
        user = request.user
        # check permission
        try:
            Punch.objects.get(pk=pk, user=user)
            return super(PunchEdit, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Punch.DoesNotExist, e:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

[HttpResponseForbidden()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseForbidden)

Comment: someone here on stackoverflow adviced me not to override dispatch method, but rather get_object or something like that. @Gocht you dont ming?

Comment: @Lucas03 I gave him some other options to do this, I think check the user permission in dispatch is simplier and I don't think this is a very big change, actually I call the real dispatch method once permission is confirmed.